# How to show and hide columns in datatable.js without AJAX request?

Tags: jquery, datatables

How can I show and hide columns in datatable.js you see I can enable and disable it BUT the problem is my datable is binded in AJAX source so it automates requests each time I show
and hide a column.

Below is the code I used but has no luck in showing and displaying columns without an ajax request.

```
$(".table-dash1").dataTable().fnSetColumnVis(0, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example from the DataTables documentation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "sScrollY": "200px",
        "bPaginate": false
    } );
} );

function fnShowHide( iCol )
{
    /* Get the DataTables object again - this is not a recreation, just a get of the object */
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();



    var bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;
    oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol, bVis ? false : true );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great answer, especially since I can't find the solution for version under 1.10. Cheers!